# Question on terminology

Tags: regression, machine-learning, terminology

When we train a model for classification, we call it a 'classifier'. When we train a model for regression, what do we call it?

The only thing I could think of was "regression model" or just "model", because it doesn't sound like correct English to say "the regression predicted a value of 0.5", whereas it does sound correct to say "the classifier predicted class 1".

Comment: I've seen the term regressor used for this.

Comment: I'd probably call it a "predictive model," but that language certainly doesn't exclude classifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just call it a model. Or, even better, refer to the independent variables in the model that are doing the actual prediction. The model is merely a means for you to understand which variables can predict your target variable.